# smoothly animated javascript stacked progress bars without flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

What is a good way of getting stacked progress bars to animate smoothly without flickering?

I'm currently using Bootstrap, changing the width styles (using Knockout).
Example: https://jsbin.com/lewuzewupo/2/edit?html,console,output
My problem is, if you watch that long enough, the green bar on the right flickers. This is seemingly because the animations cause it to get pushed to the right when the middle dark blue bar appears and disappears.

(I have tried everything I can think of to ensure that at no point in time do the total of the stacked bars exceed 100. If I stop using the progress-bar class and use my own that results in a similar look, but with no animation, then there is zero flickering and the bars are stable, always totalling 100.)

So is there a workaround for the problem in Bootstrap, or an alternative way of creating stacked progress bars that look as nice as the Bootstrap ones and animate smoothly?

[edit: added debugging to prove my percentages always total 100]

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come across this kind of thing before - it's down to the 'complete' text. Basically it's not working out the widths quite right. 2 ideas.

1. Remove the 'complete' text and it should be ok.
2. Attempt to only display complete after a certain time and the values have dropped to a particular ratio.

Sorry can't be of more help.

Comment: Sorry for the red herring, but no, it's not the text. Even with all text completely removed from all progress bars, it still flickers. It's easy to test with my demo, just do that and wait patiently.

Comment: Just reading your script, I not that you use round and also ceil. Is it possible that all your % add up to over 100 so when it flickers it moves. Sorry my knockout isn't that good.

Comment: I updated the demo to console.log if the %s do not == 100. They are always 100.

Comment: Right, cheers had a look and another play (remove values etc) I think the only thing we can both agree on is that the browser thinks the element is wider than it is and hence goes below. I think there is a good chance here that you've found a browser bug and it's doing it's own rounding with the percentages. I would suggest perhaps instead of making the percentages add to 100% change them to add to 99.7% or something.  Might do the trick.

Comment: Yes, that's my current work-around; I scale them to total 98. But it's ugly to have the space on the right hand side. I think the issue is the method of animation, which makes it a Bootstrap bug, not a browser bug; hence my question are there any other nice solutions for stacked progress bars

Comment: Maybe rework your solution. So that instead of 1 progress bar have 3. One for each of the elements and each can be a percentage of the total. Might be easier to see what each one is for.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It is currently 3 separate (but stacked) progress bars.

Comment: Yeah, don't have them stacked. Have 3 separate progress bars. i.e 3 elements. Something like this. https://jsbin.com/tininuwasa/2/edit?html,output Some reworking might be needed with the percentages - but it's an idea.